# Output option for Moscow ML compiler

Tags: sml, mosml

I am compiling some `.sml` files using `mosmlc.exe`. The problem is that `.ui` and `.uo` output files are placed in the same directory of my input `.sml` files. I would like to do something like this:

```
mosmlc.exe -o out/ src/file1.sml src/file2.sml
```

So that output files will be created in `out/` folder. But looks like `-o` option is used for something different (according to the [documentation](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/mosml/manual.pdf)). However, if I run with such an option, output files are created in the same directory as input files anyway.

How can I specify an output folder? There is no documentation on this and the compiler does not have a help option listing compiler options (very very annoying).

### From the source code

By inspecting the compiler's [entry point's source code](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/compiler/Mainc.sml#L136) I can understand that:

1. There is no help option listing all the options and usages (terrible, maybe I should consider pulling a change to support this in their repo)
2. There is no output option

So, looks like I cannot achieve this... Can you confirm that?

Comment: Looks like this is a more recent version of documentation: [manual](http://mosml.org/manual.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any solution. Maybe just a workaround using symlinks, which I'm not sure Windows provides:

```
mkdir out && \
cd out && \
ln -s ../*.{sml,sig} . && \
mosmlc -toplevel Hello.sml World.sml main.sml -o main && \
./main
```

This will create an `out` directory, `cd` into it, symlink all `.sig` or `.sml` source files into that directory and perform the compilation there.

Sorry that I gave you a Unix command, but I don't have a Windows machine to test.